# How can I group/count occurences of a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with 2 columns.

```
| Jim  | Foo |
| John | Bar |
| Jane | X   |
| Jim  | YZ  |
```

What I usually do is:

1. download the values as a CSV
2. write/run a script that processes the CSV
3. the script goes over each row, groups by the first column, and counts occurrences.
4. Then I output the values in descending order by number of occurrences.

How can I do this directly in Google Sheets using a formula?

The ordering of ties does not matter, so the expected output would be:

```
| Jim  |  2  |
| John |  1  |
| Jane |  1  |
```

or

```
| Jim  |  2  |
| Jane |  1  |
| John |  1  |
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Did you know that [tag:google-sheets] (the tag of this site) has thousands of questions and answers? Please spend some time searching the site. If you still need help, show the most relevant findings and explain why they don't meet your needs. Regarding your script, did you know that Google Sheets can be extended using Google Apps Script, which uses JavaScript as a programming language? This site also has many questions about using Google Apps Script to extend Google Sheets.

Comment: Your local script might use the Google Sheets API, but questions about how to use this API are off-topic here. They are on-topic in [so] and probably on other [se] sites.

Answer (score 0):

Do it all in [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en):

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select A, count(B)
  where A is not Null group by A 
  order by count(B) desc
  label count(B) ''")
```

OR, combine [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) and [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en):

```
=SORT(
  QUERY(A:B, "select A, count(B)
  where A is not Null group by A
  label count(B) ''"),2,0)
```

You can also [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985?hl=en) the values into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en).  This version assumes values are always in `A1:B1` pairs so the 2nd column is ignored. Also uses [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en), [TOCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13187258?hl=en), [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com,/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en):

```
=SORT(
   MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)), LAMBDA(a, 
    {a,COUNTIF(A:A,a)})),
   2,0)
```

This one only increments if there is a value in column B by swapping in [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en):

```
=SORT(
   MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)), LAMBDA(a, 
    {a,COUNTIFS(A:A,A,B:B,"<>"&"")})),
   2,0)
```

Same as previous but uses [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) and [ROWS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382?hl=en) instead:

```
=SORT(
   MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)), LAMBDA(a, 
    {a,ROWS(FILTER(B:B,A:A=a))})),
   2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIF to count the occurrences.

[image]

After that, copy the count column as values.

[image]

Last, remove the duplicates

[image]

[image]

Comment: The OP wants to know how to  *"do this directly in Google Sheets using a formula"*. Your approach involves "multiple" formulas, and then multiple additional steps.  Your answer would be improved and better reflect the question if you edited it down to a single formula.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).